# Delete specific columns in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, row, sql-delete

I need to delete a list of specific columns here is an example

I have a table that contain "numbers" and "city"

```
numbers    city

55         madrid  
55         no  
56         italia  
56         no  
57         paris  
57         no
```

I need to keep only "no" city for each number.
I tried this:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE numbers (55,56,57) and city (madrid,italia,paris)
```

I know that this will not work but its just for give you an idea of what I need.

Comment: Really close; just need some `IN`s and `'`'s.

Comment: DELETE FROM mytable WHERE city != 'no'

Comment: hi irrelephant where do i have to put in and 's ?

Comment: hi slavenko deletin all others city is not good for my case i have other citys tha i need to keep

Comment: In that case `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE numbers IN (55, 56, 57) AND city IN ('madrid', 'italia', 'paris')`. But since you're trying to do that from phpmyadmin, I'm guessing it would be easier to just select the rows with checkboxes and delete them from the table.

Comment: Thank you very much Slavenko that's really work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write: DELETE FROM mytable WHERE numbers **IN** (55,56,57) and city **IN** (**'madrid','italia','paris'**);

If you have set of strings, you have to get the string between qotes...